# XmlReader DataGridView flip column and rows

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

Using VB.NET I'm binding a DataGridView to an XML file using this code (for reading and writing)

Global:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim sFile As String = "C:\test.xml"
```

Reading:

```
Using xmlFile As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sFile, New XmlReaderSettings())
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
    gridData.DataSource = ds.Tables("data")
End Using
```

Writing:

```
ds.WriteXml(sFile)
```

Here is what the XML looks like. Now keep in mind that I fully control the layout of the XML and can change it to fit my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template validation="validationgoeshere">
    <data>
        <digit1>0.507874</digit1>
        <digit2>545541</digit2>    
        <somevalue>78</somevalue>
        <blah>0.015</blah>
        <emptyexample />
    </data>
</template>
```

I'm trying to show only one column "Data" and I want all elements within "Data" to be displayed **as rows** (with their appropriate values - innerXML). I dont' want to hardcode/specify the Rows, they need to be auto-populated with whatever it's in "Data".
Currently it shows one row and multiple columns; how can I "flip" them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final code (working):

```
 Public Function FlipDataSet(my_DataSet As DataSet) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    For Each dt As DataTable In my_DataSet.Tables
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("f"))
        table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("v"))

        Dim r As DataRow
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            r = table.NewRow()
            r(0) = dt.Columns(k).ToString()
            For j As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                r(j) = dt.Rows(j - 1)(k)
            Next
            table.Rows.Add(r)
        Next
        ds.Tables.Add(table)
    Next

    Return ds
End Function
```